# How to install the python package?

Tags: python

Please help me to resolve this issue about the install of the python package. 
There is the stack trace of my bug when I try to install the python-dateutil package using the following command:

```
apt-get install python-dateutil

Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree
Reading state information... Done
python-dateutil is already the newest version.
0 upgraded, 0 newly installed, 0 to remove and 0 not upgraded.
```

Comment: It means that the Package was already installed in your previous attempts.

Comment: This is not a "stack trace". This is `apt` informing you that dateutil is already installed - "python-dateutil is already the newest version."

Comment: If you've read your Trace Message, you'd save yourself the effort and time, it just say : "python-dateutil is already the newest version" ... which means you have already the newest version in your system installed.

Answer (score 0):

You don't have any problems, the prompt says that
    python-dateutil is already the newest version.

You can start with your work!
Good job!